# keybinding problem - shift keys remapped themselves

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Turned on my netbook (Asus X200CA) this morning to find some weird keybinding changes.  Running 14.04 with cairo dock, ran an update this afternoon to try and fix it to no avail.

Left shift key is bound to both left-shift and 3 producing a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> search if used in firefox.
3 key, intermittently, produces a left shift resulting in a £ again.

This happens in both cairo and unity desktops, in virtual terminals and in "real" terminals with no GUI loaded at all.

An external USB keyboard works flawlessly.

Help, at the end of my tether!

Comment: Typical, found a fix as soon as I posted this Q - so far it seems to work: go to dconfeditor, org->compiz->onboard, set keylabel-overrides and layout to defaults ([] and NULL (ie enter nothing) respectively)

Comment: If you found a solution, you can answer your own question --- so that the solution is easier to find for other users. Please do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical, found a fix as soon as I posted this Q - so far it seems to work:

1: go to dconfeditor, org->compiz->onboard

2: set keylabel-overrides and layout to defaults ([] and NULL (ie enter nothing) respectively)

Comment: Oh, and don't forget to come back in a couple of days to "accept" your own answer by clicking the rather drab check-mark below the (currently "2") of your answer therefore turning it into a shiny green one, helping the next user who has this problem to a "validated" answer!  ;-)