# Escape and Left Shift are stuck

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

Not sure what to make of this. Have Ubuntu 14.04 running (problem occurs with live run, and fresh installations).

My left shift when pressed also triggers the escape. It only happens on the laptop keyboard not on a usb plugin one.

The system is dual booted, and works perfectly fine in windows. So I know it is not a problem with the keyboard.

Any help on this? It makes it impossible to type in a web browser or enter a password (yes I have a capital letter in my password)

[Example of issue, only 'shift' is pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EL60.png)

**Update**

Per request, here's the output of my left shift key(no output from right key):

`showkey --ascii
^[   27 0033 0x1b`

**Update 2**

Left Shift+A Returns

```
^[   27 0033 0x1b
A    65 0101 0x41
```

Right Shift+A

```
A    65 0101 0x41
```

**Update 3**

Some potentially other useful information:

```
setxkbmap -print
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)" };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc104)" };
};
```

I have been attempting to modify. But either I completely disable shift, or I don't resolve the issue.

/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc

key   {        [ Escape                ]       };

key  {        [ Shift_L               ]       };

Comment: Does the right shift key cause the same extraneous ESCAPE sequence that the left shift key is doing?

Comment: Additionally, if you enter a terminal session and use the command [showkey --ascii], and then use the left shift key, do you get a reference to [^[   27 0033 0x1b] like you do with hitting escape?

Comment: The right shift key does not trigger the ESCAPE key. It is only the left shift (which I use :/ ). Will have to test the showkey --ascii. Will report back

Comment: Ok, next we test if the shift key is linked to two keycodes or is just being remapped as a second escape key.  Use the showkey --ascii command again, and this time give us results on LShift+A and RShift+A.  If it's a case of being dual-linked, you will get ASCII 65 on both tests (in addition to the erroneous escape).  If it's remapped, the LShift+A will give you ASCII 97 and 27 while RShift+A will give you ASCII 65.  Please tell me which in order to help narrow this down.

Comment: Thanks for your help narrowing this down. Sounds like I may need to remap the left shift? Added the request update to the question

Comment: That you are getting a capital A on both runs means that for some reason the left shift is working properly AND kicking off the extraneous escape.  I was hoping to see that left shift was just remapped as an escape (which I would know how to fix).  That it's triggering BOTH normal operation and the extraneous escape...frankly I'm stumped.  USB keyboard works properly, but the native does not (implying hardware fault).  This implication is backed by the showkey evidence, the keyboard is throwing off the extra escape.  But on the other hand Windows filters that escape out.

Comment: The suggested fix for this would be to remap the left shift to copy the right shift.  How to do that in your particular brand of linux should be google-findable.  The only other thing I can think of that might help is load up a liveUSB of a DIFFERENT flavor of linux and see if the problem is replicated there.  If not, you might consider installing that flavor of linux instead of the current one.  Please keep us informed on this one!

Comment: I'll have to try out another distro at some point to test.

This seems particularly similar to my issue: 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/582484/keybinding-problem-shift-keys-remapped-themselves

Unfortunately I am using gnome, and the solution doesn't appear to exist for me in dconf.